# Displaying data in directive, using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, directive

I am currently trying to understand Angular directives.
Right now i have made a directive, and i are using this directive in order to show a modal when a button is clicked. The modal to be shown is getting its data via an injection when it is instantiated.

The data to be used is found via an ng-repeat over an array of objects from my controller. I have tried to just plain out show the modal in each loop, and when i do this the data is just as expected. However when i try to open the modal via a button click, it shows the data from the first object regardless of what index in the ng-repeat the button is in.

My directive:

```
angular.module('myAppRename.directives', []).
directive('myModal', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  scope: {
    inv: '='
  },

  template:

      '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">' +
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
      '<div class="modal-content col-md-12">' +
      '<h1>Redigering af bilaget : {{inv.title}}</h1>' +
  '<form role="form">' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label for="title">Title:</label>' +
  '<input placeholder="{{inv.title}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="title">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label for="projekt">Projekt:</label>' +
  '<input placeholder="{{inv.project}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="projekt">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label for="ordre">Ordre:</label>' +
  '<input placeholder="{{inv.order}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="ordre">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label for="sendernote">Senders Noteringer:</label>'+
  '<input placeholder="{{inv.notes}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="sendernote">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="form-group">' +
      '<label for="dinenoter">Dine Noteringer:</label>' +
      '<input placeholder="{{inv.adminComment}}" type="text" class="form-control" id="dinenoter">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<button ng-click="editAnnex()>Send Redigering</button>' +
  '</form>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>'

 };
 }
 );
```

Using the directive in ng-repeat:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover span-8" id="myTable">


        <tr ng-repeat="inv in inventory | filter: searchKeyword">

            <td>
                <my-modal inv="inv"></my-modal>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"
                            ng-click="acceptAnnex(inv.id,inv.title)">Accepter
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" ng-click="denyAnnex(inv.id,inv.title)">Slet</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ng-click="addComment(inv.id)"> Tilføj kommentar
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#myModal"> Rediger</button>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block img-rounded img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{inv.image}}" alt=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h4> Title : {{inv.title}}</h4>
                    <h4>Sender : {{inv.sender}}</h4>
                    <h4>Projekt : {{inv.project}}</h4>
                    <h4>Ordre : {{inv.order}}</h4>
                    <h4>Senders Noteringer : </h4>
                    <p class="thumbnail">{{inv.notes}}</p>
                    <h4>Din kommentar : </h4>
                    <p class="thumbnail">{{inv.adminComment}}</p>
                </div>

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Cant really understand why this might be happening, so any suggestion, or hint in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `#myModal` as the ID for **every single modal on the page**.  When you reference a modal by `#myModal` you're not getting the one you want because ids are supposed to be unique.

You need to generate:

`id=myModal1` , `id=myModal2` , ... (one unique id for each modal on the page) inside your iterator and then your target should be

`#myModal1` (or whatever the appropriate one is.)

Comment: This makes sense..
I will try to do that and get back to you, thanks for the hint. 
If this solves my problem ill mark this as te answer.

Comment: This worked out great. Looked at the documentation for ng-repeat, and used the $index, +1 to make the id for the modal.
Thanks for the help !